# How to load an external website in a div with out iframe

Tags: html

How to load an external website in a div? I must not use an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Uframe

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/uframe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [object](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT), which will be treated a bit like an iframe, but with less consistent browser support (making it a **very** poor alternative to an iframe). I've only seen this used in exercises to use HTML Strict when Transitional (or a redesign to avoid the feature) is called for.

You could parse the data from the remote server on your server and bundle it in up in the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... Conceivably, you could write the content of a webpage gotten via a curl request to the innerhtml of a div... I'm postulating, of course; I have no desire to try this out, but here's some code if you'd like to give it a whirl...

Some server-side php... let's call it `pageloader.php`

```
<?php
// Check for cURL
if( !function_exists( 'curl_init' ) ) die( 'cURL is not installed.' );

// Create a cURL resource handler (cURL Handler = ch)
$ch = curl_init();

// Set options
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://www.example.com/"   );    // URL from which to download
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         0                           );    // Include header? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true                        );    // Return or Print? (true = return, false = print)
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10                          );    // Set a maximum time before timeout (defined above)

$output = curl_exec( $ch );

curl_close( $ch );

echo $output; ?>
```

Then a little javascript... I'll just assume you're going to do a specific page on page load...

```
window.onload = function() {
  var req = encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById('ajax_location').value );
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  xmlhttp.open( "GET", "pageloader.php", false );
  xmlhttp.send( );
}
```

And finally your index.html, where presumably you'd be displaying another's hard work as your own inside a massive div:

```
<body>
  <div id="output" style="width:960px;height:480px;overflow:scroll"></div>
</body>
```

Of course, this might just end up as a bunch of unrendered html, but it was a fun bit of mental calisthenics anyhow.

Answer (score -3):

You can use iframe in Div for to call external web site in it.